# Azure functions: Use Apollo Azure handler in async function

Tags: typescript, azure, azure-functions, apollo, apollo-server

I want to wrap my apollo handler into an async function, to perform some checks before the handler function is executed. Everything works fine, when I don't use an async function but exporting the function as async returns always an empty response.

functions.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "$return"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/graphql/index.js"
}
```

The setup:

```js
    import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
    import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-azure-functions';
    import { Context, HttpRequest } from '@azure/functions';
    
    import { resolvers } from '../src/graphql';
    import { authChecker } from '../src/auth';
    
    const schema = buildSchema({
      resolvers,
      authChecker,
    });
    
    const server = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      context: ({ context }) => context, // directly use azure Context as Apollo context,
    });
    
    const handler = server.createHandler();
```

This works

```js
export default (context: Context, request: HttpRequest) => {
  handler(context, request);
};
```

this returns always 204, empty response

```js
export default async (context: Context, request: HttpRequest) => {
  // do async stuff: await ... 

  handler(context, request);
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to return data from a Node.js Azure function:

- [returning data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#outputs) from an `async` function
- passing data to the [`context.done()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#contextdone-method) method

In your code, `handler` is a method from `apollo-server-azure-functions` package. Internally it calls `context.done()` to send the response back to Azure runtime.

But because `handler(context, request)` itself is a regular function call, your exported top-level `async` function resolves without waiting for it to finish.

You may want to return a Promise from your async function which will resolve when the underlying apollo server is ready to send the response. Here's an [example implementation](https://github.com/maximivanov/azure-function-graphql-typescript-starter/blob/main/graphql/index.ts).